# is it worth upgrading from 14 AWG to 12 AWG

Tags: electrical

I am looking to replace all the OLD 14/2 wiring in my "new to me" house with 12/2 wiring do you believe this is over kill?

Comment: What do you seek to gain? There's nothing inherently wrong with 14 AWG wiring (as long as the breakers are properly sized), so what is it you want to do that the 14 AWG wire doesn't let you do? If you just need more load capacity somewhere, then just add new runs to that location.

Comment: In the high end homes I helped build the lights were 14G and recepts were 12G. Your kitchen recepts need to be 12G at least anyway... Make sure your fridge, dishwasher, and microwave are on dedicated circuits.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, no.

## Additional Capacity

If you need the additional capacity on a single circuit, you'd be better to simply replace that single circuit, or add an additional circuit.

## Additional Outlets

If you're adding additional outlets (I'm talking outlets (lighting, receptacle, etc.), not just receptacle outlets), consider installing a new circuit rather than expanding an existing one.

## Technology Upgrade

If you're replacing the wiring anyway (removing old knob & tube, etc.), you'll want to install 20 ampere circuits with 12 AWG conductors where appropriate. Though it still may not make sense to simply install all #12 wire.

## Free Wire

If you have a ton of 12 AWG wire laying around that you got for free, and you just feel like spending hours pulling cable. Go ahead.

Comment: +1 Also 12 AWG is harder to pull, bend and attach. It is also harder to seat switches and receptacles in boxes. Where you need it great; where not, skip it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to consider, you are talking about a complete house re-wire. Are the walls all open? If not, do you plant to gut the house? If not, are you aware of the scope of this job?
Also, just asking about 12/2 vs 14/2 is hardly accurate. You'll need 12/3 for some circuits and wiring patterns, and larger wire for some other circuits like a dryer or range. I assume you are just asking about #12 vs #14.

There is ABSOLUTELY NOT safety advantage of #12 over #14. DoO not let the "bigger is always better" crowd tell you different. 
Pulling in the cable is not really an issue at all. What does become a big issue is box fill in switch boxes. Using #12 for lighting, especially with 3-ways, 4-ways, and boxes with dimmers, can very quickly over fill legal box capacity and can make installing dimmers very difficult. 
Even for lesser receptacle circuits, like bedrooms, #14 is FINE. You have to consider what will be used on the circuits. It's not the number of receptacles on a circuit, it's what's being plugged in. This is why kitchens, bathrooms and laundries require 20A receptacle circuits, where most other rooms do not.

Answer (score 2):

I will add a little reality to the conversation.  #12 wire is used for circuits that will require more power to them compared to #14.

But that is a misnomer too since if you are designing a house wiring system can limit the amount of things that one single circuit does.  If a circuit will power an appliance, tools, machinery, garage, or will have heavy constant usage then yes it needs #12/20A.

However we are cycling out of heavy power usage.  Things are made to be more energy efficient.  We have LED and CFL lighting.  This trend will only continue.  In 20 years we will see appliances that repurpose energy.

Honestly I wouldn't care if my house was all #14/15A minus kitchen appliances and heater/AC.  If anything having a lower breaking point would tell me as a consumer that I am doing something wrong.

For instance I had an old compressor that I should have thrown away years ago...  I used it on jobs and in my basement all the time.  Basement was all 12/20A.  Well first time I tried it in an upstairs bedroom it kicked the breaker within 1 min.

I am not saying that having reduced power ability is THE barameter for finding energy hogs or issues.  I am saying why not?  It is cheaper, just as safe, and easier to work with.

And to answer the $ question.  Is it worth it resale-wise.  NO.  I have flipped many houses.  Having #12 vs #14 wouldn't get you an extra $5 unless an electrician is buying your house.  Unfortunately almost any electrical upgrade will not add much value to your house compared to the cost associated with it.